# best way to combine git repositories

Tags: git, github

I'm looking at the best way to use a single or multiple git(hub) repositories in a new project, so that I can pull updates from the original git source.

So if I have foo.git and bar.git and I start a new project baz.git. What is the best way to have foo and bar in the baz repository? Should I just clone them in the new directory or use git merge or something else?

I don't want to lose the history and connection to the original repo for foo and bar because I still would like to pull updates when needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is **git submodule**

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule  :

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a
>   dedicated subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a
>   particular commit.
>
> They are not to be confused with remotes, which are meant mainly for
>   branches of the same project; submodules are meant for different
>   projects you would like to make part of your source tree, while the
>   history of the two projects still stays completely independent and you
>   cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main
>   project.

more info about submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules